# Powershell generic error: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: excel, powershell-2.0

I know this is a very generic error message and I have spent many hours looking through similar questions without any luck.

Here is my PowerShell script producing this error:

```
$ExcelObject = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
$excelProcessId = ((get-process excel | select MainWindowTitle, ID, StartTime | Sort StartTime)[-1]).Id
$ExcelObject.visible = $true
$ExcelObject.DisplayAlerts = $true

$folderpath = "C:\myfiles\TESTER.xlsx"
$Workbook = $ExcelObject.Workbooks.Open($folderpath)
$WorkSheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item("TAB1")
$sourceList = "value1,value2,value3"
$missing = [system.type]::missing
$sourceRange = $WorkSheet.Range("A3:A22")
$sourceRange.Validation.add(3,1,$missing,$sourceList,$missing)

$Workbook.save()
$Workbook.close()
$ExcelObject.Quit()
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Workbook)
[void][System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ExcelObject)
[GC]::Collect()
Remove-Variable ExcelObject
Stop-Process -Id $excelProcessId -Force
```

resulting error:

```
Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:11 char:1
+ $sourceRange.Validation.add(3,1,$missing,$sourceList,$missing)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

I have tried to use the value list directly but same error:

```
$sourceRange.Validation.add(3,1,$missing,"value1,value2,value3",$missing)
```

I replaced the $missing but same error:

```
$sourceRange.Validation.add(3,1,1,$sourceList)
```

I have no more ideas on how to resolve this issue and would appreciate any suggestions.
Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem: the specified range had to be cleared of any existing validation:

```
$sourceRange = $WorkSheet.Range("A3:A22")
$sourceRange.Validation.Delete()
$sourceRange.Validation.add(3,1,$missing,$sourceList,$missing)
```

I feel a little embarrassed, but maybe it is of use to someone down the line.